# How to test Arduino board?

Tags: arduino-uno, bootloader

A little history: I have two Arduino Uno and I couldn't program them by IDE, I got these errors:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
```

So I googled it for a while and I suspect of missing bootloader on atmega micro on the board, as I don't have AVR programmer I programmed both Arduinos with Raspberry Pi and Arduino IDE tool through ICSP pins.

It (burning bootloader) runs perfectly on both Arduino. One of them got fixed and got back to normal, but the other one gave me same error, so I changed their Atmega micro, but same result. Second Arduino (bad one) can't transfer program to AVR even with other one (good one) AVR so both AVRs on the boards are good.
The program (blink LED) run even on the bad Arduino and pin 13 blink.

My questions are:

How could I test the suspected Arduino board? Is the second Atmel micro near usb female port need bootloader too?

> **Update 1**: I follow [this tutorial](http://bartruffle.blogspot.com/2013/09/dfu-programming-atmega16u2-on-arduino.html) but my Arduino couldn't go to DFU
>   mod by shorting the pins. When I connect those pins led pin 13 not blink and lsusb command show Arduino not Atmel.
>
> **Update 2** : I went through [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13292/have-i-bricked-my-arduino-uno) and [this
>   troubleshoot](http://www.gammon.com.au/bootloader) to upload bootloader to Atmel USB device but my
>   second Arduino (bad one) didn't respond and gave me this error :

```
Atmega chip detector.
Written by Nick Gammon.
Version 1.17
Compiled on Jul 13 2015 at 11:14:35 with Arduino IDE 105.
Attempting to enter ICSP programming mode......................................................
Failed to enter programming mode. Double-check wiring!
Programming mode off.
```

> Is it possible my Atmega16U2 chip is burned?
>
> **Update 3** : I do reach the point that I am pretty sure Atmega16U2 is
>   dead and it isn't responding to its ICSP pins and it blocks any USB to AVR connection. I check the wiring and I
>   test it on good Arduino and its sequence are correct and it works on good one. Now what can I
>   do, as Atmega16U2 is not rechangeable, should I throw bad Arduino away?

Comment: See http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13292/have-i-bricked-my-arduino-uno and see if that helps.

Comment: Do you have anything connected to the serial? (Pins 0 and 1)

Comment: @TheDoctor No sir, all pins are free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is for your 3dr Update - should you throw it away?
I'd say no, if you are comfortable with using the Raspberry PI as programmer, as you already did.
You will not be able to use the USB-based programming, nor you will be able to emulate USB peripherals, but that's it.

Everything else will (or should) work normally, so why would you throw it away? :-)

I also suggest you grab the stronger magnifying lens you can find and have a look at the soldering of all the components. Especially those connected to the Atmega16U and the chip itself. Maybe it's not broken, but there is some short caused by conductive debris or by some excess of soldering material. If that's the case, it might be easy to remove it.

Comment: The problem is i can only upload bootloader with rasberry pi but i can't upload sketch into it. I don't know why ?

Comment: I don't know either (although it might have to do with the bootloader interfering with further uploads), but I see 2 options, at roughly the same price: either throw away the arduino and buy a new one (3-4 euros on ebay) or buy an USBASP (about 4-5 euros on ebay). The USBASP should be able to program the main AVR, as long as it is alive. And it might be useful if you do - on another board - something which requires reprogramming the Atmega16U, so you can simplify the upload process.

Comment: Btw, the USBASP would also enable you to save a bit on future purchases of arduinos: with the USBASP you can program also the mini-pro flavor of arduino, which is basically the same micro on a much smaller PCB, without USB connector. Price < 2 euros.

Answer (score 0):

does the built-in arduino LED light up?? If yes try connecting your arduino in another uno usb port or try pressing the reset button on your arduino uno.

Comment: The power LED light and i test it with other cable and i even used reset button trick, non of them works.