# Arduino UNO not working?

Tags: arduino-uno, motor

Recently I assembled my Shapeoko machine, we used Grbl shield with an Uno for the same.

For 1-2 weeks everything worked perfectly then once when I tried to work the machine, the serial communication was not working. I tried to replace the 16 MHz oscillator because I thought the problem might be with the oscillator since the LEDs were not blinking but they were lighting up.

Comment: Please visit [Have I bricked my Arduino Uno?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13292/have-i-bricked-my-arduino-uno-problems-with-uploading-to-board) and see if the steps suggested there help solve your problem.

Comment: Did you mean 16MHz and not 16Hz?

Comment: Maybe the 5v regulator? Hard to say without the symptoms.