# Arduino Uno not Detecting on Laptop

Tags: arduino-uno

I have an Arduino Uno. The story is I installed Arduino IDE and Drivers before even buying an Arduino Board. I used it a little and when I bought and connected an arduino board, I was unable to make it detect. I smacked a little usimg google and was able to somehow Fix this. but again another day, It worked a little and started creatimg problems. now its not detecting. Please suggest me a way To make it work...
Should I format my windows 7 and Reinstall all the drivers as per rules?

Comment: Is this a genuine Uno or a cheap clone? `Should I format my windows 7` - no, I doubt that would achieve anything.

Comment: Its a cheap clone. Can You suggset a measure to fix this ??

Comment: Clones tend to need different device drivers than a genuine board. Did it **ever** work?

Comment: when i first connected, it did not work. but i tried to make it work. and after 3 hours i could make it work. i tested blink programs and controlled a servo using diffrent sketches. but another day, its not detecting on my laptop. Last time I had uploaded Blink program. When i connect the board with computer, the 'ON' led and Onboard pin 13 LED blinks as per program. But my computer cant detect it at all.

Comment: I installed the driver of that clone from that link but no effect

Answer (score 1):

under the IDE make sure you have set the correct board and comm port. go to tools>>board then choose your board then tools>>Comm to choose the correct comm port.

is the IDE saying anything about having problems connecting to the board?

and no re-installing all drivers should not be necessary.

Comment: When I goto tools >> comm The selection area is greyed and inactive.
should i Try to Reflash the atmega ??

Comment: That means it really isn't detecting the arduino at all. Try unplugging the arduino for about 3 minutes, then plug it back in on a different USB port. 

Is the arduino a genuine one or a clone? do you have a link to where you bought it?

Comment: Slow down a bit. Don't reflash the Arduino. Don't re-install Windows 7. Do you want to change houses as well? Try to do some simple debugging. I don't understand this part: `I smacked a little usimg google and was able to somehow Fix this`.

Comment: Please see [Have I bricked my Arduino Uno? Problems with uploading to board](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13292/have-i-bricked-my-arduino-uno-problems-with-uploading-to-board).

Comment: Yes, my computer is not detecting the arduino at all. Today, I re-installed Windows 7, but still not detecting. "I smacked a little usimg google and was able to somehow Fix this" means that when I got this problem, I searchd this on Googl and re-installed arduino drivers. It startd working but only for a day. Nxt day, Sam Problem. How Can I try debugging, as you said??

Comment: One more thing, Last time I had uploaded Blink program. When i connect the board with computer, the 'ON' led and Onboard pin 13  LED blinks as per program. But my computer cant detect it at all. Is my cable damaged ?? If yes then how my board can draw power from That usb and not the programming functions? Product Link : http://www.ebay.in/itm/Arduino-UNO-R3-ATmega328P-ATmega16U-compatible-Development-Board-USB-Cable-/252024502692?hash=item3aadd4b9a4