# Is my Arduino Uno broken?

Tags: arduino-uno

I think I broke my Arduino Uno as I was playing with it. I connected an ultrasonic range finder to it and uploaded a sketch to it. It was working fine until I accidentally touched the ICSP headers for the USB interface (the pins near the USB port). Now,everything is still working but my computer cannot detect it and it does not show up in the device manager or the IDE. Please tell me if it is broken and how to fix it.

BTW, I just bought it and just started using it after another Arduino had the same problem.

Comment: What have you tried? At the very least I'd try unplugging the Arduino and rebooting the computer (or in some way forcing a reset on the USB). The Uno may be particularly sensitive, but I've not seen a problem like this with any of my Arduino (and clone) boards. Do you live someplace where static electricity is a problem (I don't).

Comment: touching the ISP header or port should not have caused damage. Can your PC detect other usb devices on the same port?

Comment: Get down to just the bare Arduino board, disconnect everything, and see what you get..  the Ultrasonic sensor could easily be pulling more power than your USB can supply, only about 500mA.

Comment: I have tried deleting the arduino software and downloading it again, I also unplugged the arduino and rebooted my PC but it. I also tried installing older versions of the IDE but it still did not work. My PC cannot detect any other USB devices on the same port. I tried disconnecting everything but it still does not work.

Comment: Try other USB port and another computer. If you wish you could try and reprogram the 16u2. If it does not respond it's dead but you can always either replace it or use the Arduino for things that do not require serial.

Comment: It did not work. I just bought an arduino mega instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Please tell me if it is broken and how to fix it.

See [Have I bricked my Arduino Uno? Problems with uploading to board](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13292/have-i-bricked-my-arduino-uno-problems-with-uploading-to-board)

Those tips may also help with fixing problems with your Mega (if you ever have them). ;)