# panstamp device signature is random

Tags: rf

I Have 2[panstamp](http://panstamp.com). I can program the first but not the second with the arduino program.

When I upload the sketch (a simple blink) on the second, I got this

```
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.03s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x004e22
avrdude: Expected signature for ATmega328P is 1E 95 0F
Double check chip, or use -F to override this check.

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

And if I retry, I got this.

```
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.03s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x81f014
avrdude: Expected signature for ATmega328P is 1E 95 0F
Double check chip, or use -F to override this check.

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

The device signature is not the same anymore ... 
I've changed the wire and re-open arduino program. But it don't change, the device signature change (often 0xE1E1E1). I've check the connection between the ATmega and the wire and everything is ok.

Is the Panstamp broken ? or should I do a kind of factory reset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the Panstamp broken ?

Sounds like it. If one works, and the other does not, using the same wiring, it looks like you have a faulty one.

> or should I do a kind of factory reset?

You can't really "factory reset" a chip like that. Possibly there is a problem with the fuses. You may be able to explore further here:

[Have I bricked my Arduino Uno? Problems with uploading to board](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13292/have-i-bricked-my-arduino-uno-problems-with-uploading-to-board)