# Arduino does not work

Tags: c++, c, programmer

When I try to upload a sketch to my Arduino Uno R3 then sometimes I get the following issue:

At the beginning the RX LED flashes three times and then I get errors:

```
    avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd1
    avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd1
    avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd1
    avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd1
    avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd1
    avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd1
    avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd1
    avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd1
    avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd1
    avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd1
```

Sometimes I get this:

```
    avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM3": Odmowa dostępu.
```

And sometimes Windows does not see the Arduino.

At this site [Have I bricked my Arduino Uno? Problems with uploading to board](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13292/have-i-bricked-my-arduino-uno-problems-with-uploading-to-board) I read that to check the programmer I must to connect RX with TX and GND with RESET pins and then plug Arduino to my computer, open Serial Monitor and write anything and if you receive the same characters from the Arduino, then the programmer and USB cable are OK. It worked for me.

And I have got one more info. When I plug Arduino with USB to my laptop the L led lights. When I press Reset on Arduino nothing happens, it still lights.

I recently bought a new USB cable, and it worked one day and then I could not upload sketches again. I uninstalled and installed drivers, but nothing changed.

This is a short video with my Arduino https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByeWvrEgy2gRbWdHQ3d5RWU3Mmc/view?usp=sharing

[image: Photo of Uno]

---

I will buy USBasp programator is it a good idea?

Comment: I am not sure about that particular error. But, have you set the right board and port on the arduino IDE?

Comment: Yes i checked it and I have right board and com port, but thanks for comment.

Comment: Restart your PC, "Access denied" is because something/some program is using your COM port. Or might have not been closed correctly by another upload or program.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal that the `L-LED` is steady `on` after the USB connection is established. However, after pressing and releasing `Reset` it should flicker for a second, then go back to `on` again.

Check https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#toc1 for reasons why you can't upload.

On http://www.arduino.org/products/boards/4-arduino-boards/arduino-uno I've found:

> The Arduino Uno has a resettable polyfuse that protects your computer's USB ports from shorts and overcurrent. Although most computers provide their own internal protection, the fuse provides an extra layer of protection. If more than 500 mA is applied to the USB port, the fuse will automatically break the connection until the short or overload is removed.

I haven't found out so far, how to read the current values of the fuses.

Comment: I will buy USBasp programator is it a good idea?

Comment: But when I click reset the l-led is not flicker

Comment: From the first link: Make sure there's a bootloader burned on your Arduino board. To check, reset the board. The built-in L LED (which is connected to pin 13) should blink. If it doesn't, there may not be a bootloader on your board.

Comment: @JanOkoński If you have no other Arduinos then yes, it's always a good idea to have a USBasp programmer. Make sure you get the one with 3.3V/5V mode, USBasp itself programming jumper and the right cable to program regular Arduinos. (http://g01.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1PB8pKpXXXXc3XVXXq6xXFXXXz/AVR-USBASP-Programmer-ATMEGA-ATMEL-downloader.jpg) Should cost just as much, but has much more features.

Answer (score 1):

1. Serial could be flooded if you were spamming it in ur last program you uploaded.
2. Ur arduino is broken
3. Try reflashing ur bootloader which is a common problem when you see data sync errors.

Answer (score 0):

> I will buy USBasp programator is it a good idea?

Yes, buy the USBasp programmer, reflash the bootloader with it, and try uploading code again. A corrupted bootloader very well may be the problem.