# sketch uploading give error?

Tags: arduino-uno

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x30
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x0f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x10
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x20
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x0f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x10
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x30
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x0f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x10
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x20
```

Comment: See [Have I bricked my Arduino Uno? Problems with uploading to board](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13292/have-i-bricked-my-arduino-uno-problems-with-uploading-to-board) - your "question" is very light on detail.

Comment: Most often this message indicates that you should select another board type in the Arduino IDE under Tools menu. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

This [Instructables post](http://www.instructables.com/id/A-solution-to-avrdude-stk500getsync-not-in-syn/) has a list of potential causes for this error. Is this a new board? What board are you using? Is it a genuine Arduino board or a clone? Have you been able to upload to the board previously?

Comment: I have selected right com port. Previously i had uploaded sketches and that worked find. Now it giving me issue.

Comment: I am using clone arduino

Comment: @user3883017 What is your hardware setup? Do you have any wires connected to the RX pin?

Comment: Arduino UNO. No Just one LED to pin 13 and ground

Comment: avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Apr 15 2015 at 19:59:58
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM7
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the atmega328 chip? If you have the new one may not have a bootloader or it may have one for a different board. Select every board option. Duemillemova maybe? 
If you still have no luck, you might have over written your bootloader. Try burning the bootloader again. Instructables shows you how.