# Is my Arduino mega dead?

Tags: arduino-mega

I accidentally short-circuited my Arduino mega(ended up connecting the 5V and ground pins). Physically from observation nothing seems to be burnt on the board but I am not able to upload new codes to it again. I am quite sure that the last code I uploaded still run on it because when I plug it in all seems to be normal.
I tried to upload codes to it with the CP2012 programmer I use for my pro mini and that doesn't help either.
Is there any way I can manage to upload codes to the board again or it is dead?

Comment: Well, is it still short circuited? What did the old sketch do? And how can you be sure that it is still running? With the CP2012, you can't use the DTR pin to move the reset, you know? So just connect +5v, gnd, rx, tx and start uploading. When the IDE tells you "uploading", briefly press the reset button on the mega and see if it works

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? (by "it" I meant both your PC and Mega)

Comment: @frarugi87 I am familiar with the manual reset approach, it doesn't work with my mega but works with my pro mini.

Comment: "_when I plug it in all seems to be normal._" What do you see or measure to indicate a normal board? E.g. LED behavior, measured outputs, some response to inputs?

Comment: @DannyGH with that adapter you should have the autoreset feature on the pro mini, so you don't have to manually reset it..

Comment: See [Have I bricked my Uno](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13292/have-i-bricked-my-arduino-uno-problems-with-uploading-to-board) - a lot of that applies to the Mega too. There is a sketch mentioned on that page you can use to test the processor chip with.