# Diagnosing crashed Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, raspberrypi

I have an Arduino Uno connected to a motor controller over I2C. The Arduino accepts commands from a Raspberry Pi via the USB serial line.

I'm trying to diagnose a problem where the Arduino will become completely unresponsive. It's programmed to respond to a "ping" request every N seconds, and for some reason I can't identify, it seems to crash and no longer respond to any commands. However, the motor controller continues powering the motors.

Everything is powered from a 12V Li-Po battery, but everything is located behind 5V regulators. When this problem happens, the battery is fully charged and the motors aren't sourcing much current, and neither the motor controller or Raspberry Pi are effected, so I've ruled out a brownout.

My theory is there's some subtle programming error in my Arduino code that's causing an "exception", but I don't know how to identify it. I've tried adding special code to allow me to trigger one of these, by indexing an array outside of its limits or calling a null function pointer, but the Arduino stubbornly refuses to crash when I try to explicitly make it.

How do I diagnose an Arduino becoming unresponsive?

Comment: `and for some reason I can't identify, it seems to crash and no longer respond to any commands.` - how long does this take? Minutes? Seconds? Hours?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't have access to a debugger, the most common way is to add debug logging. The ususal algorithm to solve those problems is more or less like this:

```
do {
    add_logs_in_suspicious_places();
    wait_until_it_crashes();
    analyze_logs();
} while( ! i_know_why_it_crashes() );
```

If you cannot add any debug logging because of a flawed system design (lack of I/O, etc) you've commited a captial engineering crime and this is your punishment. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent [post](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13292/have-i-bricked-my-arduino-uno-problems-with-uploading-to-board/13293#13293) by Nick Gammon that covers a wide array of possible problems. Look into this, as might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you have spare pins, add debugging LEDs. For example, toggle one at the start of `loop`, another at the start of another function, and so on. When the Arduino "crashes" the state of the LEDs should provide a hint as to where in the code it is.

> but the Arduino stubbornly refuses to crash when I try to explicitly make it.

Typically you are indexing outside an array or using uninitialized memory. Your debugging code has moved the problem around enough to stop it happening (or appearing to happen).

If you amend your question and post your code we might spot something.