# How do I Continuity Test/Troubleshoot a Linksprite RS232 V2 Shield?

Tags: softwareserial, rs232, arduino-uno-smd, max232

I have a Linksprite RS232 v2 adapter (which uses a MAX232 chip), as per [this image](http://linksprite.com/wiki/images/a/a6/SHD_RS232_V2_1.jpg). I have soldered on the headers and tested the pins to make sure there are no solder bridges. I have set the jumpers so that D2 is set to TX and D3 to RX. However, I can't establish comms through the device using the Software Serial library, regardless of how I set the jumpers. (Real Term doesn't show me anything when a USB-to-Serial adapter is connected. However, if I change the baud rate to 9600, I get about 5 bytes of `0x00`, then nothing.)

If I disconnect the shield from the Arduino board then supply 5V to pin 2 or 3 (from an Arduino) and connect pin 5 of the DB/E9 to the Arduino's GND, I get output from both pins 2 and 3 (RX/TX) on the DB/E9 (regardless of which pin on the board is powered). The voltage between pins 2 and 3 on the connector differs by ~0.1V. Is this normal or is my circuit faulty? How do I test the continuity of the board/connector and diagnose and fix the fault?

In case it's of any relevance, I'm using an Uno with an SMD chip.

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope, or logic analyzer, or more than one Arduino?  If you only have a DVM, with jumpers off run a sketch that toggles different digital pins at about .5 Hz, and verify that that shows up ok on pins of J2 on the shield.

Comment: I don't have an oscilloscope or logic analyser (or know how to use one). I do have a DT830B multimeter and multiple boards (Uno R3, Leonardo R3, Mega 2560 R3).

Comment: It turns out that [the ATMega328P-PU chip on the Uno I was using is damaged](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13292/have-i-bricked-my-arduino-uno-problems-with-uploading-to-board). I will try again with a different board and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @JamesWaldby-jwpat7 Thank you for the suggestion. I managed to get access to an oscilloscope and test the shield with a different board. It helped me diagnose that the RS232 shield is non-functional.