# Arduino uno R3 Not detected in windows 7 64

Tags: arduino-uno

i have 3 arduino uno r3 out of which 1 is not detected in any of my Pc's,

i was working and must have accidentally short circuited some how , the power led and 5v regulator on uno is burnt out but,i replaced both of them, but then again, windows was unable to detect it,but if i remove and plug the atmega328p in another uno it works fine.am able to upload sketch and do work,and put back the atmega in the non functioning uno.

the uploaded sketch runs fine but not detected, its kinda tiring removing the atmega and uploading a sketch through another uno and putting it back and the pins are so delicate each time i pull carefully somehow the pins getting bent.

i also checked other components on the board but everything seems to be in good shape and not heating or anything, hope some has better solution...

Comment: It's dead, Jim.  A common issue when you short circuit seems to be that the ATMega16U2 chip dies in some way and the USB never works again.

Comment: Maybe you can check the answer in the following question to prevent it next time: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/43188/burning-arduinos-one-after-another/43190#43190

Comment: hi, i tried uploading the sketch using an FTDI breakout board with 5V selected connecting as
GND       GND  
CTS       not connected
VCC       5V
TxD       D0 (RX)
RxD       D1 (TX)
DTR       To RESET  after hitting upload the progress bar gets struct at 100% after taking too long i get this error :programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x83
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x83
goes about 10 attempts, is there anything wrong in my connection?