# Is my Arduino Micro bricked?

Tags: bootloader, arduino-micro

A few weeks ago I built my own Arduino Micro. Everything worked fine and it connects every time. I have built a second one, with the exact same processor schematic as the first one. It turns on, and I was able to bootload it with an Arduino Uno, just like the first one. But it will not connect to my computer.

When I plug it into my PC, the lights flash on but I get nothing. It does not show up in device manager anywhere, and its like I plugged nothing in, in the first place.

When I plug in my other Arduino Micro it works fine. But this one does not. I have tried switch PCB's (maybe the first one was bad) but nothing seems to work. I have even switched the ATMega32U4, but I still get the same issue.

When I connect my multimeter to the USB port and the corresponding D+ and D- pins on the processor, I get that there is resistance and there are no crossed connections.

I feel that at least the computer should say "Device not recognized," but I just get nothing. Is my Arduino bricked? Has anyone else had a similar problem?

Comment: `I was able to bootload it` ... are you really sure?

Comment: Yes I am **really** sure, the bootloader said done in Arduino and the Blink Sketch started running. Even if it wasn't bootloaded the ATMega32U4 should still show up in device manager.

Comment: have you tried another usb cable? ....... unplug all arduinos from the computer. remove the arduino micro driver by using the `windows device manager`, then plug in the bad arduino, to see if it may enumerate correctly. it is possible that windows will not talk to the second arduino because it is detecting something that does not match the first arduino (windows is pretty weird when it comes to USB devices)

Comment: Be sure to check out the answers on a very similar question: [Have I bricked my Arduino Uno Problems with uploading to board](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/13292/19409)