# Missing arduino bootloader problem?

Tags: bootloader

I have a arduino clone that is not being assigned a /dev/tty by Debian Stretch (Stable).  It does have the ch340g chip.  I have tried the driver from the manufactures site with no joy.  Would the lack of a bootloader cause this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Trying a random manufacturer driver makes no sense on a Linux system, the proper CH34x driver is already in the mainline kernel sources.  To figure out what is actually wrong you should start with `dmesg` and `lsusb`.

Comment: Been there done that.  And the source is from the Actual board manufactures site. usb 2-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
[136679.079624] usb 2-1.3: device descriptor read/8, error -32
[136679.207639] usb 2-1.3: device descriptor read/8, error -32
[136679.314532] usb 2-1-port3: unable to enumerate USB device

Comment: this information should have been in your question when you posted it . ... please update your question with this info (use the `edit` button)

Comment: What is actually wrong with the board is a different question than was asked.  Though again, despite being irrelevant to the actual issue, with Linux you all but *never* want to use a manufacturer's driver, and definitely not when there's a known-good and actually code reviewed one in the mainline kernel sources.

Answer (score 2):

No.  On Arduino-style boards which use distinct chips for the main processor (ATmega328p) and Serial interface (CH34x/ATmega8u2/ATmega16u2/FT2232 etc) the presence or absence of a bootloader on the main processor has no bearing on the recognition of a USB/Virtual Serial device by a host.

However on ATmega32u4 and some ARM-based boards it can.

Since you are describing a classic board with distinct chips, whatever your actual issue is, it is something else.

Comment: Figured as much.  I was just hoping that when a new board gets here I could install a bootloader to it and have it start working.  So I expect that the chip is bad and I have a brick.  To bad it would cost as much to send it back as it cost in the first place.

Comment: If you desolder the USB chip the ATmega processor might still be good.

Comment: See [my question & answer about debugging board issues](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13292/have-i-bricked-my-arduino-uno-problems-with-uploading-to-board)