# Arduino pro micro might be bricked

Tags: arduino-leonardo, arduino-pro-micro

I bought an Arduino pro micro (looks like [this](https://www.bazaargadgets.com/image/cache/catalog//products/electronics/arduino/ATMEGA32U4MiniUSBDevelopmentBoardForArduinoLeonardo-SKU207354-2-800x800.jpg)) from a Chinese seller over E-Bay, for its HID interface.

I installed the Arduino software on my Linux machine (Kali Linux), and started writing a USB Rubber Ducky script, and converted it to Arduino using [Dckuino.js](https://seytonic.com/ducky/), which usually works just fine.

I may have used either:

- The wrong programmer, or
- The wrong board type

because when I uploaded the sketch, it said it failed, but HID script still worked when I plugged it into my Mac.

The Mac came up with a `Keyboard Assistant`, because it couldn't recognize the keyboard being use. So I plugged it back into my Linux machine, and it wouldn't recognize.

- `lsusb` and `dmesg -w` didn't show any updates when re-plugging the Arduino.
- Changing USB chords didn't work.
- Switching over to windows, `Device Manager` didn't do the normal "refresh" when you plug in a new device, and there was nothing under `COM Ports`.
- The HID input didn't work on the Mac anymore, when plugging it in again.
- The inbuilt LED lights up when connected.

Is this a brick?
I can't seem to find any `reset` button or header on the board, so I cant connect the ground and reset.
There is an `RST` header, but I don't know what that is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: RST = ReSeT.  Have you tried re-flashing the bootloader through ICSP?

Comment: Be sure to check out the answers on a very similar question: [Have I bricked my Arduino Uno Problems with uploading to board](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/13292/19409)

Comment: Connecting the RST header to ground (GND) with a wire should be the same as pressing the reset button on other arduinos.

Comment: Do I need to solder on the wire, or can I just kind of hold it there?

Comment: Don't play with RST. Get another arduino. Load programmer sketch. And try to load bootloader over icsp. Select programmer "arduino as isp"