# Unlocking Digispark ATTiny85 after flashing it to HID

Tags: arduino-ide, attiny85, digispark, hid

I made a simple test sketch to make my ATTiny85 emulate a Keyboard and send a sequence of keystrokes.

```
#include "DigiKeyboard.h"
void setup() {
  // don't need to set anything up to use DigiKeyboard
}

void loop() {
  DigiKeyboard.delay(1000);
  DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(0);
  DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(106); // F15
  DigiKeyboard.delay(59 * 1000);
}
```

It worked fine, but now every time I plug it to the USB port on my computer, Windows detects it as a Keyboard and starts typing what I programmed it to type.

Arduino IDE can't reprogram it. When it says "Plug in device now", I do it, but it immediately acts like a Keyboard, not like a programmable ATTiny85.

[image: Arduino IDE]

*Note: Image shows the console output. Code is just a simple blinker.*

Is there any way to save this board? I just want to upload another sketch to it. Maybe some way to rewrite the bootloader or to erase the flash memory entirely.

Also, please give me some advice so I can avoid being locked out again in the future. I really want to use this board as a Keyboard emulator, but I want to be able to reprogram it if necessary.

[image: ATTiny85]

Comment: Please don't post images of code.  Just copy and post your code into the editor, and then format it as a *code sample*.

Comment: @sempaiscuba the code is not the important part of the image... The console output is.

Comment: add the console output as text, not a picture

Comment: use a switch or a jumper to enable the keyboard code

Comment: You have nothing connected to the board at all except the computer?

Comment: This board is a tricky one, because the bootloader cannot be protected. -- As you describe it, you do everything correctly. After starting the upload, the board needs to be connected, so that its software starts. Commonly you disconnect the board before starting the upload. If the bootloader is present, it waits for 5 seconds for the uploader of the PC, before it launches the user application. -- Anyway, if the uploader does not connect to your board, the bootloader might be overwritten. -- Did you try to remove the device in the Hardware Manager? Windows might get into the way.

Comment: @timemage, yes, that's correct. Nothing is connected to the board, except the computer on the USB connection.

Comment: @thebusybee, Yes, I tried to remove the device in the Hardware Manager, but when I reconnect it, it shows up again. I also tried to replace the driver using Zadig (to libusb-win32) and now Windows doesn't detect it as a keyboard as before... but I still can't write a new sketch to it.

Comment: Well, then I'll assume that you lost the bootloader. There are multiple resources in the web that describe how to flash the bootloader. You should prefer the instructions of the manufacturer or similar serious site. Or buy a new device.

Comment: Yeah, I could just buy a new one, upload a new sketch and being locked outside again, the same way I am now... That's not sustainable, It should not be impossible to upload a new program multiple times. That's what this question is about: How to fix this specific board and how to prevent from being locked out again.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't access the bootloader using USB your remaining option is ISP/ICSP (In-Circuit Serial Programming). I have that digispark board and I have never been able to program it using Arduino's IDE/USB. However, since then I always use both an USBasp programmer and the AVRDUDESS programming tool. With them you can eassily program the controller (they have never failed me). Connect the SPI, +5V, GND and RESET connectors from the ATTINY85 to the programmer, compile the code, program the binaries with AVRDUDESS and voila.

Comment: Hello. Could you please add more details to this answer? What is USBasp? AVRDUDESS? Which "programmer" are you talking about? Is it a separated device?

Comment: I added some details to my response. Yes, USBasp is a separate device, a programmer typically implemented with an Atmel AVR controller. You can easily buy them from Ebay or someplace else. AVRDUDESS is a GUI tool to help you flash the compiled binary into the target controller, i.e., the attiny85 in this case.

Comment: You can learn a lot from [Have I bricked my Arduino Uno? Problems with uploading to board](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13292/have-i-bricked-my-arduino-uno-problems-with-uploading-to-board)